# Dynamically update "Status" column after "X" amount of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, web-services, stored-procedures

I'm rather new to SQL Server, but I am working on an app where a record is added to a table, and is given a `DateTime` stamp.

I want to be able to dynamically update  the `Status` column of this row, 1 hour after the row was added.

Is this possible without running some server side script or store procedure every couple minutes? Is there an efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: You would have to execute an update statement at some point. This seems a little odd to me but whatever. You could do this with a sql job that runs every X minutes and update the status to your desired result. Make sure your update includes a where predicate to only update the rows that need to be. Another option might be to dynamically retrieve the status when you select the data from the table. It still seems weird that a status changes when nothing happens other some ticks on the clock.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any performance issues with running a job that frequently in the background?

Comment: Absolutely there a performance concern. That isn't to say it can't or shouldn't be done. But you are talking about running a sql statement on the clock. If your statement is written well the performance impact should be negligible. If however, your query is inefficient it can effect performance significantly.

Comment: I would attempt to go with some sort of dynamic derivation, like M. Ali proposed in his answer, or have the application performing the insert track and make the update.  Any sort of script on the SQL server side will have to find the one row you want to update, so unless your script can somehow filter down to that one row, it's still going to have to scan multiple rows to update just the one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sql Server you can have `Time Dependant` or `Action Dependent` code execution.

### Time Dependent

Time Dependant Code execution is handled via SQL Server Agent Jobs. You can execute a stored procedure or ad-hoc T-SQL code on a certain time of the day. It can be scheduled to execute on regular basis.

### Action Dependent

Action Dependent Code execution is handled via Triggers (After/Instead of Triggers). A piece of code that is executed in response to a DML action INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE.

### Solution

In your case you are trying to execute code in response to an action (Insert) after a certain period of time. I dont think there is an efficient way of doing it I would rather do the following....

You can have a Column called Created of `Datetime` datatype in your table and set a `default value` of `GETDATE()`.

Now you dont need the status column. All you need is a query/View which will check at runtime if the row was added more than an hour ago and will return it STATUS as required.

Something like.....

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_Current_Status 
AS
SELECT * 
     , CASE WHEN  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Created, GETDATE()) >= 60
             THEN 'OLD'
           ELSE 'New' END AS [Status]
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution.  Thanks!