# How to refresh a stored procedure and a table automatically every 30 mins?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks, sql-server-agent

I have a stored procedure returning some result sets. I have created a table and I am inserting the results of the stored procedure in this table. Now what I want is, I want to refresh the stored procedure  as well as the table every 30 mins.

```
Here is my stored proc.,

USE [my_DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_1] 
@Week int = 1,
@Year int = 2014
AS
BEGIN
declare @current_week int
set @current_week = datepart (week, getdate()) 
while @Week <= @current_week
begin
truncate table [my_DB].[dbo].[tb_name]
insert into [my_DB].[dbo].[tb_name]
exec sp_2 @Week,@Year
select @Week as Week_Number,* from [my_DB].[dbo].[tb_name] (nolock)
set @Week = @Week + 1
end
END
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this? An example would be more helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You can create a job that runs every 30 minutes

Comment: Google [`SQL Server Agent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189237.aspx)

Comment: and google why you shouod NEVER name stored procs sp_

Comment: Also have a look here [`Dynamically update “Status” column after “X” amount of time`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166271/dynamically-update-status-column-after-x-amount-of-time)

Comment: Use crontab if Linux, AT if windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best anwser is to configure a Job that runs every 30 minutes but also you can do something like this:

```
Salto:
    Exec sp_1;
    Waitfor Delay '00:30:00';
Goto Salto;
```